# Неправильно работает открытие уровней unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Когда игрок доходит до финиша, должен открыться 1 следующей уровень, а открывается сразу 2 следующих уровня.

Код при победе:

```
int currentLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
if (currentLevel >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levels"))
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levels", currentLevel + 1);
}
```

Код для открытия следующего уровня:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    int levelUnLock;
    public Button[] buttons;

    void Start()
    {
        levelUnLock = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levels", 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <levelUnLock; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = true;
        }
    }

    public void loadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: А у Вас сцены с уровнями с 0 или с 1 начинаются? Просто насколько я понял, кнопки с уровнями начинаются с 0, а сцены с уровнями с 1. Получается, что если у Вас по факту пройдено только 2 уровня (сцены 1 и 2), в currentlevel запишется 2. Но по факту разблокируется 3 кнопки (с 0 по 3).

Comment: @SoulOFTrue немного не понял вопроса. В build settings сцены с уровнями начинаются с цифры 2. 0-главное меню, 1-выбор уровней, 2,3,4,5,6 - уровни

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю ответом предположение.

Вот это:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <levelUnLock; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].interactable = true;
    }
```

Попробуйте заменить на это:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <levelUnLock-1; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].interactable = true;
    }
```

Это некрасивое решение, исключительно для того, чтобы проверить предположение

Comment: Вы бы лучше перенесли текст и коммента в ответ, раз уж решили его запостить.

Comment: Теперь нельзя запустить первый уровень, и получается что все уровни заблокированы

Comment: Ну тогда деактивируйте их не с 0, а с 1, чтобы первый уровень при любых условиях был открыт.

Comment: @SoulOFTrue спасибо, все работает