# Один скрипт для нескольких кнопок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю список заданий для игры, на каждой миссии присутствует 1 единственная кнопка для получения награды. На каждую миссию я накинул скрипт, а после в инспекторе указал кнопку и прочие значения. При выполнении миссии и нажатии на 1 кнопку для получения награды, блокируются все кнопки вместо одной нужной.

Как можно реализовать адекватную систему получения награды и блокировки одной из нужных кнопок, без задевания других? У меня написан единный скрипт для нескольких миссий.

```
public class MissionsElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int colClick;
    public int PlusMoney;
    public static int dostup = 1;
    public GameObject button;

    private void Start()
    {
        dostup = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("block", dostup);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("block", dostup);
        if (dostup == 0)
        {
            button.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }
    }
    public void OnClickButton()
    {
        if (Game.clicks >= colClick)
        {
            if (1 == dostup)
            {
                Game.Money += PlusMoney;
                dostup = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас вопрос по коду, но код вы конечно же не покажете.

Comment: не хочу ваше здоровье портить,но ладно,если что,я не виноват..

Comment: А у миссии есть идентификатор, номер, имя или что-то такое? Как их отличить друг от друга?

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1302800/373567

Comment: @aepot, отличаются лишь названиями

Comment: Следовательно в префы надо класть не просто block, а что-то уникальное для этой миссии. Например mission3_block, где число для каждой миссии свое. Ну или что-то другое придумайте, что вам удобнее.

Comment: спасибо,попробую.

Comment: @aepot,изменил название у кнопок,Миссий и прочего на более отличительные,по новой всё закинул на скрипт
все равно,при выполнение 1 задания,блокируется не 1,а сразу все кнопки которые есть в списке

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе, у меня с телепатией слабовато.

Comment: Но я не про код сейчас..

Comment: Тогда вы не поняли, о чем я вам выше писал. Перечитайте еще раз внимательнее.

Comment: Вв предлагаете добавить мне несколько элементов по типу public Button button_1,button_2 и т.д?

Comment: Давайте так поступим: ответ я удалил, так как он хоть и не сломал ничего, но и не помог. Вы сейчас обновите код в вопросе на актуальный. И добавьте деталей, про префы и все что мне в комментах писали. Придут более крутые спецы, чем я и может помогут разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Миссия и плашка миссии в меню это два разных объекта. Плашке должно быть пофиг какую миссию отображать. Это префаб с ссылкой на элементы в префабе (кнопкой для взятия награды, текстами для имени и описания, иконкой, линией прогресса и т.д.) и функцией, получив ссылку на миссию всё это визуальное дело обновлять.

```
public class MissionView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action Compleated;
    [SerializeField] private Button _collectButton;
    [SerializeField] private Slider _progress;
    [SerializeField] private Image _icon;
    [SerializeField] private Text _title;
    [SerializeField] private Text _discription;
    private Mission _mission;

    public void SetMission (Mission mission)
    {
        _mission = mission;
        _mission.StatusChanged += UpdateButton;
        _mission.ProgressChanged += UpdateProgress;
        UpdateButton();
        UpdateProgress(_mission.Progress);

        _icon.sprite = _mission.Icon;
        _title.text = _mission.Title;
        _discription.text = _mission.Discription;
    }

    // указано OnClick кнопки в инспекторе 
    public void TakeReward ()
    {
        _mission.TakeReward();
        Compleated?.Invoke();
    }

    private void UpdateButton ()
    {
        _collectButton.interactable = _mission.Compleated;
    }

    private void UpdateProgress (float value)
    {
        _progress.value = value;
    }
}
```

Ну и какой ни-будь `MissionViewController` создаёт нужное количество префабов вьюшек под доступные миссии и удаляет выполненные.

```
public abstract class Mission : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action StatusChanged;
    public event Action<float> ProgressChanged;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite _icon;
    [SerializeField] private string _title;
    [SerializeField] private string _discription;
    private float _progress;

    public bool Compleated { get; private set; }
    public float Progress => _progress;
    public Sprite Icon => _icon;
    public string Title => _title;
    public string Discription => _discription;

    public abstract void TakeReward ();

    protected void Compleat ()
    {
        Compleated = true;
        StatusChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    protected void SetProgress (float value)
    {
        _progress = value;
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(_progress);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class KillMonter : Mission // пример префаба миссии
{
    [SerializeField] private MonsterType _target = MonsterType.Goblin;
    [SerializeField] private int _count = 10;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private CurrencyType _rewardType = CurrencyType.Gold;
    [SerializeField] private int _rewardAmount = 100;
    private int _counter;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        MonsterManager.Instance.Killed += OnMonsterKill;
    }

    private void OnMonsterKill (MonsterType type)
    {
        if (type == _target)
        {
            _counter++;
            if (_counter < _count)
            {
                SetProgress(_counter/(float)_count);
            }
            else
            {
                MonsterManager.Instance.Killed -= OnMonsterKill;
                SetProgress(1f);
                Compleat();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void TakeReward ()
    {
        CurrencyManager.Instance.Earn(_rewardType, _rewardAmount);
    }
}
```